# Part of proof of $f+g$ is measurable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $f:X\to \Bbb R$ and $g:X\to \Bbb R $ be measurable real-valued functions, I read about the proof of $f+g$ is measurable as the following:

> If $r$ is a rational number, then $S_r=\{x\in X: f(x)\gt r\}\bigcap\{x\in X:g(x)\gt \alpha -r\}$ belongs to $X$. Since it is seen that $\{x\in X:(f+g)(x)\gt \alpha\}= \bigcup\{S_r:r\in \Bbb Q\}$, it follows that $f+g$ is measurable.

I want to show in details why $\{x\in X:(f+g)(x)\gt \alpha\}= \bigcup\{S_r:r\in \Bbb Q\}$. I already proved the direction that as $f(x)\gt r,g(x)\gt \alpha-r$, it implies $f(x)+g(x)\gt r+(\alpha-r)=\alpha$, so that $ \{S_r:r\in \Bbb Q\}\subset\{x\in X:(f+g)(x)\gt \alpha\}$ for all $r$.

But, I have trouble proving the other direction: $\bigcup\{S_r:r\in \Bbb Q\} \supset \{x\in X:(f+g)(x)\gt \alpha\}$. Could someone show in details why this is true? Thanks.

Comment: That is Lemma 2.6 from Bartle's *The Elements of Integration*, in case someone searches for an explanation like I did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $f(x)+g(x)>\alpha$ then some $r\in\mathbb Q$ can be found with $r<f(x)$ and $r+g(x)>\alpha$.

That means exactly that $x\in S_r$.

Just approach $f(x)$ from below with elements of $\mathbb Q$.

If e.g. $(r_n)_n$ is a sequence in $\mathbb Q$ converging to $f(x)$ with $r_n<f(x)$ for each $n$ then $r_n+g(x)\to f(x)+g(x)>\alpha$ so that eventually $r_n+g(x)>\alpha$.

Essential in this proof is that $\mathbb Q$ is dense in $\mathbb R$ and is countable as well.